# Check if only one kind of element is consecutive in a list?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to create a list to use for an experiment. The list will have 30 elements where 10 will be "T" and 20 will be "NT" in a random order. "NT" can be next to each other but none of the "T" elements should be consecutive.

T = target trials
NT = non-target trials
In case you need the context

I've looked into various questions but they seem to be checking if *any* of the elements are consecutive, not just one particular kind of element. I only want to make sure "T"s aren't consecutive.

Here is the code I've got so far

```
import random

trial_ratios = random.sample(range(30), 30) #generate a random list of 30 nums with no duplications
target_trials = []

for i in trial_ratios:
    if i < 10: # target trials
        target_trials.append("T")
    else: # non-target trials
        target_trials.append("NT")

print(target_trials)
```

Which gives an output like this
`['NT', 'NT', 'T', 'NT', 'NT', 'T', 'T', 'NT', 'NT', 'NT', 'NT', 'T', 'NT', 'NT', 'T', 'T', 'NT', 'T', 'NT', 'NT', 'NT', 'NT', 'NT', 'NT', 'NT', 'NT', 'T', 'NT', 'T', 'T']`
As you can see, occasionally "T"s will be produced consecutively.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, is it something like: do you wanna print "No" when Ts are consecutive?

Comment: @Shashwat I'm thinking of something like having a variable to check for consecutiv-ity and when True, it will keep generating new sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls = ['NT', 'NT', 'T', 'NT', 'NT', 'T', 'T', 'NT', 'NT', 'NT', 'NT', 'T', 'NT', 'NT', 'T', 'T', 'NT', 'T', 'NT', 'NT',
      'NT', 'NT', 'NT', 'NT', 'NT', 'NT', 'T', 'NT', 'T', 'T']

for i in range(len(ls)-1):
    if ls[i] == "T" and ls[i+1] == "T":
        print("There are consecutive T's")
```

Refer to this code for checking consecutive (T) in a list. Further you can add break after print statement if you don't consider how many pairs of consecutive T are present in list

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using a slightly modified version of this.

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient but you can do something like this

```
import random

MAXTRIALS = 30
MAXT = 10
target_trials = ['NT'] * MAXTRIALS

tCnt = 0
while tCnt < MAXT:
    randomIdx = random.randrange(MAXTRIALS)
    if target_trials[randomIdx] is 'NT' and \
            (randomIdx == (MAXTRIALS - 1) or target_trials[randomIdx + 1] != 'T') and \
            (randomIdx == 0 or target_trials[randomIdx - 1] != 'T'):
        target_trials[randomIdx] = 'T'
        tCnt += 1

print(target_trials)
```